# Stop postback from XMLHttpRequest's callback function

Tags: callback, postback, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to stop postback from happening if a certain condition is met in the XMLHttpRequest's callback function. I've used return false from within the function, but the postback happens anyway. Is there a way to stop it in such a case?

Comment: if the call back is async, the postback is going to occur anyway? An initial thought may be to make the call synchronous if possible?

Comment: I've tried that but there was no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the callback function is called the postback has already happened so it will be to late to try to stop it.

The callback is called by the XMLHttpRequest once it receives the result back from the server.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that might be the case.